# Schedule ec2 instance start/stop

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to schedules the time, around which an ec2 instance starts/stops? Is it possible to do it without using cron, aws data pipeline or Lambda? I am trying to create a shell script to automate this task. Please suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Lambda function which will help you start or stop any instance which have correct tags with start and stop values.

https://gist.github.com/gregarious-repo/b75eb8cb34e9b3644542c81fa7c7c23b

You just need to create new function with proper permission and trigger it by the CloudWatch event which will execute every minute.

Once you have it up and running your instance tags should look like  below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shell script along with aws cli to get this done.

Incase your ec2 instance is in an auyo scaling setup or if you can place it in an auto scaling setup, you can use the scheduled autoscaling featute as well. You can read about scheduled auto scaling feature here. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/schedule_time.html

Note: Auto scaling feature is free to use and coats only for resources that is used up. You may place single instance setups also in auto scaling setup with minimum value set to 0 and use scheduled autoscale feature to get your purpose served.